# VSCode - Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:english_words/english_words.dart'

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

I just got started with Flutter, following the google codelab for First Flutter Application.

I have tried all the previously answered solutions but none have worked for me.

**Tried:**

`flutter packages get`,
`flutter packages upgrade`,
`flutter pub get`,
`flutter upgrade`,

`flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"`

Flutter and Dart Plugins are installed in Android Studio as well.

Restarted multiple times too.

`english_words-3.1.5` package is already present in `.packages`

Attaching Screenshot links for reference

[image: .packages]

[image: pubspec.yaml]

Answer (score 0):

Try running `flutter clean` from your Vs Code terminal.
Then restart.

Comment: It didn't help ;(